# Servidor Django de producción carga imágenes extremadamente lentas

Tags: python, django, imagen, despliegue

Tengo un problema con el despliegue de una aplicación en python Django donde los usuarios pueden cargar algunas imágenes. La aplicación en el entorno de desarrollo localhost funciona perfectamente y muy rápido.

Pero al desplegar en el servidor y ejecutar como producción la carga de imágenes es muy lenta (varios minutos), si la imagen supera el 1MB el tiempo de carga es tan largo que el subido de la imagen se cancela. Estoy utilizando un servidor Nginx y Gunicorn.
En resumen mi problema es que si corro como producción, mi sitio tiene imágenes extremadamente lentas para cargar y subir. No sé por qué está mal y no me muestra ningún tipo de errores y tengo una gran diferencia en la carga de tiempo. Yo uso Ubuntu como servidor

Comment: Depende mucho de las características del servidor que uses para producción. Es recomendable usar soluciones y proveedores en la nube si esperas una alta demanda. Además te recomiendo usar una CDN para distribuir contenido estático, ya que estas estarán optimizadas para servir contenido en menos de un segundo. Además debes de limitar el peso de la imagen que se sube al servidor, eso hará que evite la carga y trabajo excesivos. Cuando trabajas en _localhost_, es normal que los datos carguen más rápido, porque la conexión no recorre internet, sino que se queda en tu propio dispositivo.

Comment: Parece un tema de ancho de banda. Si la estás alojando localmente, recuerda que todo servicio residencial tiene una fracción de velocidad de subida de la que tiene de bajada. Por eso es mejor contratar un servidor o alojamiento dónde no tengas esas restricciones, o bien contratar un servicio profesional simétrico, en el que la velocidad de subida y de bajada son la misma, que suele ser mucho más caro que el típico servicio residencial o de oficina.  Obviamente, si estás corriendo localhost, el ancho de banda es ilimitado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El caso es que tengo un proyecto en django el cual está desplegado en un servidor rentado de buenas características ya para la producción utilizando Nginx y funciona correctamente excepto al momento de querer subir una imagen a cualquier modelo que tenga definida alguna de hecho demora tanto la carga que se cancela la subida de la imagen
El sistema no me muestra ningún error tanto en pantalla como en consola solo se queda colgado hasta que se cae La carga de una imagen de 1MB puede tardar hasta 7 minutos colgado Este comportamiento solo ocurre en el servidor de producción en local funciona

Comment: @LuisAlfredoBaez es normal que en el entorno local funcione sin problemas, esto se debe a que cuando intentas cargar la imagen, la petición tiene que recorrer internet para conectar al servidor de destino y al cliente. Cuando estás en un entorno local, la petición no recorre internet, sino que se queda en tu mismo equipo que será mucho más rápido. También depende de la carga de trabajo, es decir las solicitudes y las cantidades de los datos. También es importante optimizar el código. Incluso puedes optar por usar una CDN o servidores en la nube para optimizar la carga.